# How to send data from one component to another using a shared service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services

I wanted to send data using subject to another component (for a earning purpose).  I am not able to fetch back the data. Here is my code:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { shareService } from './share.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <hello></hello>
  <button (click)="passData()">
    Start
  </button>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers:[shareService]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private service : shareService){}

  passData(){
   this.service.send("hello");
}

}
```

**hello.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { shareService } from './share.service';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  providers:[shareService]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private share : shareService){
    this.subscription =  share.subj$.subscribe(val=>{
    console.log(val);
    })
  }
}
```

**share.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class shareService{

  private sub = new Subject();
  subj$ = this.sub.asObservable();

    send(value: string) {
    this.sub.next(value);
  }

}
```

I am not getting the value in console.

Here is the working Demo : [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/common-service)

Comment: if you want to go deep and see how data can be shared between modules this will interest you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089316/how-to-share-service-between-two-modules-ngmodule-in-angular2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By putting:

```
@Component({
  .....
  providers: [sharedService]
})
```

in both components, you are creating two distinct instances of the shared service.
Each instance is not 'aware' of the data from each component. 
Provide it at module level and create a singleton service:

```
@NgModule({
  ....
  providers: [sharedService]
})
```

This way, you inject the service as a single instance in the both components, so they can share it as they will share the data.

Or using the [Angular's preferred new way](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service) :

> Beginning with Angular 6.0, the preferred way to create a singleton
>   service is to specify on the service that it should be provided in the
>   application root. This is done by setting providedIn to root on the
>   service's @Injectable decorator:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/common-service-wt5ydr?file=app/app.module.ts)

See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45877589/5468463)

Comment: But should'nt it work if i provide it in each component separately?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-remove-components . Here is the demo of it . I have a close button on each element , if close it , my component is getting deleted , but why i am not able to add the same component again ?EG :  If i close component 1 and try to add it again it's not working . Where am i making a mistake

Comment: From quick reading, it seems to me that when you destroy the parent component and shared service are not notified of the change

Comment: when i close it , ngOnChange is not getting fired . Is this the reason ?

Comment: What should i do it to change ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154065/discussion-between-sampath1504-and-vega).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why sub$ is used but you dont need that

```
// just push data to subject. you can use BehavourSubject to initiatte a value.
@Injectable()
export class shareService{

  private sub = new Subject();

    confirmMission(astronaut: string) {
    this.sub.next(astronaut);
  }

}
```

And then in your 2nd component sub scribe it

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  providers:[shareService]  // this can be shared in module lebel or componenet level
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private share : shareService){
    this.subscription =  share.subj.subscribe(val=>{
    console.log(val);
    })
  }
}
```

make sure to provide your service in module level or provide it in both the component.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986548/when-to-use-asobservable-in-rxjs is a good practice to expose an internal subject only through the observable interface

Comment: So using asObservable is good right?

Comment: I never used that. The way I explaned I alwasy use it. for me its extra line of code and need to whrite and maitnain

Comment: @Sampath1504 its about hidding the internal implementation of your shared service and  the observer behavior of the subject, when your component (client) only cares about the observable behavior of it

Comment: @Jota.Toledo  and Aniruddha Das . Can you help me with this . This is my demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-remove-components   .  I have a close button on each element , if close it , my component is getting deleted , but why i am not able to add the same component again ?EG : If i close component 1 and try to add it again it's not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141132/angular-2-ngonchange-not-firing-on-deletion-of-component?noredirect=1#comment79244765_46141132 . Here is my question . I dont know where i am making a mistake