# Global Service - getting value is undefined

Tags: angular

> `"@angular/common": "^5.0.0"`

I searched a lot about it and most say to do it that way ... What am I doing wrong?

My intuition says that every time that I build (constructor) another component, the GlobalService will be clean, but I don't know how to do this correctly...

**GlobalService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService{
  private currency;
  constructor() {
   }
  setCurrency(val) {
      this.currency = val;
  }
  getCurrency() {
      return this.currency;
  }
}
```

**GlobalService Module**

```
@NgModule({
  ...,
  providers:[ GlobalService ]
})
```

**Setting Value (Any Component)**

```
import { GlobalService } from '.path/global.service';

constructor(..., private global: GlobalService) { }

anyMethod(){
  this.global.setCurrency('Test Global Service');
  console.log(this.global.getCurrency()); // On console => Test Global Service
}
```

**Getting Value (Another Any Component)**

```
import { GlobalService } from '.path/global.service';

constructor(..., private global: GlobalService) { }

anyMethod(){
  console.log(this.global.getCurrency()); // On console => undefined
}
```

Comment: Is Another Any Component rendering before Any Component?

Comment: @SiddAjmera, No, after

Comment: Have you added `providers:[ GlobalService ]` to the `@Constructor` of any of these two components? If not, is one of your Modules lazily loaded? If not, please consider replicating this issue on a Sample StackBlitz and share it across so that it could be looked into.

Comment: Thinking like: LoginView (AnyComponent) set the email on GlobalServie and I can use that email in all of other components... I currently use localStorage to do this and I want to use a Global now

Comment: Ok, I'll create a StackBlitz

Comment: Simplest way to check if there actually are multiple service instances created: just add some console output to service CTOR. Most likely would still be that one component calls getCurrency() before another has set a value.

Comment: I create a StackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qrvaxy) and worked like I want .... but on my project (above) don't work

Comment: @RonaldKorze, I did what you told me to do and it's creating multiple instances... So, how do I create a singleton? I searched for this too, but the most is for Angular 6

Comment: Where is your GlobalServiceModule imported? You need to make sure it's only imported once and that either in the app module or if you have a core module.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig, only on `app.module.ts`

Comment: Any one have any idea about what can I try to solve this? Or some reference for me to study more

Comment: Solved with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47213845/10647645