# How to fetch id from one component to other using angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 components present in one ts file.
TS:
This is present in one component

```
addSubCategory(boat:Boat):void {
    const reff = this.dialog.open(AddSubCategoryDialog, {
      data: { }
    });
    const sub = reff.componentInstance.onBoatSubAdd.subscribe((data) => {
      this.boatSubTypes.boat_type_id = boat.id;
      this.service
          .addSubBoat(data)
          .subscribe(
            response => {
              console.log(response);
              this.dialog.closeAll();
              this.dialog.open(AddSubCategoryDialog);
              this.loadAllBoats();
            }, error => {
              this.snackBar.open('Failed to add company', 'X' , {
                duration: 2000,
              });
            });
   });
  }
}
```

I need to fetch the boat.id present in this file to the below given function
This is present in one more component but within same TS file:

```
add(boatSubTypes:BoatSubTypes): void {
    this.addClicked = true;
    this.boatSubTypes.boat_type_id = this.boatSubTypes.boat_type_id;
    this.onBoatSubAdd.emit(boatSubTypes);
  }
```

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried the use of shared service?

Comment: no, how to do that?

Comment: Not a best example, but could help, specially the demo:https://stackoverflow.com/a/45988033/5468463. Tell me if it helps. otherwise there are lot of posts on SO that should be helpful too

Comment: ya thank you i will check and lt you know